# How to stop background scaling-down when menu item is active?

Tags: html, css, menu, transition

Hope everyone's fine!
Despite the title, I have 2 questions, hope you can help me.

Number 1. When I click/touch a menu item, the background of the items is scaling-down too. I'd like the background to stay fixed, and only the text to scale down.

Number 2. With a burger menu, how can I give a transition time when the menu unfolds? I did a hamburger menu using the input method (I just started learning JS). I saw a guy on yt (Kevin Powell) setting the menu height to 0 when the input was unchecked, and when it was checked giving the menu the necessary height, then giving it a transition time and all was done and working. Unfortunatelly, for some reason (or some mistake I did) if I tried giving it a height of 0, I had all the menuitems staked on eachother and I couldn't figure out a way to do it with height 0, so I had to work with display none. Now, I can't give it a soft unfolding transition.

I posted the code (which could be messy, so sorry for that) and I also linked the website so you can see it "at work". [Website here](https://amicidizampa.netlify.app)

Thank you all very much!

```css
.hamburger {
  font-size: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  top: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: .1s;
}

.hamburger:active {
  transform: scale(.8);
}

.hamburgerinput {
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburgerinput:checked~.menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 89px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  display: none;
  transition: .3s;
}

.menuitem {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 43px;
  transition: .3s;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  font-size: 47px;
}

.item {
  transition: .2s;
}

.menuitem:hover {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}

.item:active {
  transform: scale(.8);
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, lightblue, rgba(200, 200, 200, .7));
}

.current {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
}

.contatti {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <label class="label" for="burger"><img src="images/hamburger.svg" class="hamburger" width="63px" alt="icona menu"></label>
  <input class="hamburgerinput" type="checkbox" id="burger">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item home"><a class="current menuitem menuitemactive" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item cani"><a href="cani.html" class="menuitem menuitemactive">Cani</a></li>
    <li class="item gatti"> <a href="gatti.html" class="menuitem menuitemactive">Gatti</a></li>
    <li class="item comeaiutarci"><a href="comeaiutarci.html" class="menuitem menuitemactive">Come aiutarci</a></li>
    <li class="item contatti"><a href="contatti.html" class="menuitem menuitemactive">Contatti</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting max-height to 0. The content of the menu can be styled like this.

```
.content {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

Now, you can add an event listener on the hamburger icon(which I suppose you click to reveal the menu). When it is clicked, have a function like this:

```
renderContent() {
    let maxHeight = window.getComputedStyle(content).maxHeight;
    if (maxHeight === '0px') {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
}
```

I have implemented this in one of my projects. Let me know if you need more calrity.

Thanks.

Comment: I will try to implement it in my code. when i click the burger icon, the menu unfolds moving down all the content above. how can i make it unfold over the other content? with z-index?

Comment: Yes, you can try z-index. Can you please provide link to codepen?